# Cache<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>> combined with Striped<ReadWriteLock>: is it thread-safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, guava

I've implemented `PeersContainer` class with all operations that I need. I need something like multimap in concurrent environment, moreover  I need remove entities automatically on timeout. So, I decide to use `Cache<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>>` combined with  `Striped<ReadWriteLock>`. Also I use two caches which can transfer entities between each other.

***Question:*** *Is all those operations thread-safe in my context?*

If it isn't thread safe, please, provide an example which demonstrate scenario where I'll get inconsistent data.

```
public class PeersContainer {

    private final static int MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 100;
    private final static int STRIPES_AMOUNT = 10;
    private final static int PEER_ACCESS_TIMEOUT_MIN = 30;

    private final static PeersContainer INSTANCE;

    static {
        INSTANCE = new PeersContainer();
    }

    public static PeersContainer getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private Striped<ReadWriteLock> stripes = Striped.lazyWeakReadWriteLock(STRIPES_AMOUNT);

    private final Cache<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>> peers = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
            .expireAfterAccess(PEER_ACCESS_TIMEOUT_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .removalListener(new RemovalListener<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>>() {
                public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<Long, BlockingDeque<Peer>> removal) {
                    if (removal.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
                        //send logOut response to all use'r {@code Peer} objects.
                        for (Peer peer : removal.getValue()) {
                            //peer.sendLogOutResponse();
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();

    private final Cache<Long, UserAuthorities> authToRestore = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
            .expireAfterWrite(PEER_ACCESS_TIMEOUT_MIN, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    public BlockingDeque<Peer> getPeers(long sessionId) {
        Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).readLock();
        peers.cleanUp();
        lock.lock();
        try {                
            return peers.asMap().get(sessionId);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean addPeer(Peer peer) {
        long key = peer.getSessionId();
        Lock lock = stripes.get(key).writeLock();
        lock.lock();
        try {                
            BlockingDeque<Peer> userPeers = peers.getIfPresent(key);
            if (userPeers == null) {
                 userPeers = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Peer>(); 
                 peers.put(key, userPeers);
            }
            UserAuthorities authorities = restoreSession(key);
            if (authorities != null) {
                peer.setAuthorities(authorities);
            }
            return userPeers.offer(peer);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void removePeer(Peer peer) {
        long sessionId = peer.getSessionId();
        Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).writeLock();
        peers.cleanUp();
        lock.lock();
        try {                
            UserAuthorities authorities = null;
            if (peers.getIfPresent(sessionId) != null) {
                authorities = peers.getIfPresent(sessionId).getFirst().getAuthorities();
                authToRestore.put(sessionId, authorities);
                peers.getIfPresent(sessionId).remove(peer);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void removePeers(long sessionId) {
        Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).writeLock();
        lock.lock();
        try {                
            peers.invalidate(sessionId);
            authToRestore.invalidate(sessionId);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private UserAuthorities restoreSession(long sessionId) {
        Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).readLock();
        peers.cleanUp();
        authToRestore.cleanUp();
        lock.lock();
        try {                
            BlockingDeque<Peer> activePeers = peers.getIfPresent(sessionId);
            return (activePeers != null && !activePeers.isEmpty()) ? activePeers.getFirst().getAuthorities() : authToRestore.getIfPresent(sessionId);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 1. Thread safety

From a concurrency stand-point, I don't see any issue with the code: reading is guarded by the `readLock`, all the updates are guarded by the `writeLock`, and you're using thread-safe `BlockingDeque`s for the values.

However, you're returning the actual `BlockingDeque<Peer>` from the `Cache` in `getPeers()`, so you're not mandating going through your `PeersContainer` to manipulate the values. You depend on how the other objects collaborate.

## 2. Other considerations

From a more general stand-point, I'd make a few changes:

### 1. Consistent API usage

> ```
> public BlockingDeque<Peer> getPeers(long sessionId) {
>     Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).readLock();
>     peers.cleanUp();
>     lock.lock();
>     try {                
>         return peers.asMap().get(sessionId);
>     } finally {
>         lock.unlock();
>     }
> }
> ```

Why use `asMap()`? I'd stay with :

```
return peers.getIfPresent(sessionId);
```

### 2. Intermixing blocks

Especially with locks, I like them close to where I use them. So instead of

> ```
> Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).readLock();
> peers.cleanUp();
> lock.lock();
> ```

I'd write

```
peers.cleanUp();
Lock lock = stripes.get(sessionId).readLock();
lock.lock();
```

### 3. Multiple look-ups

Even if `Cache` is fast, no need to abuse it :). In `removePeer()`:

> ```
> UserAuthorities authorities = null;
> if (peers.getIfPresent(sessionId) != null) {
>     authorities = peers.getIfPresent(sessionId).getFirst().getAuthorities();
>     authToRestore.put(sessionId, authorities);
>     peers.getIfPresent(sessionId).remove(peer);
> }
> ```

can be replaced by (also fixing the unconditional `getFirst()` call):

```
BlockingDeque<Peer> userPeers = peers.getIfPresent(sessionId);
if (userPeers != null && !userPeers.isEmpty()) {
    UserAuthorities authorities = userPeers.getFirst().getAuthorities();
    authToRestore.put(sessionId, authorities);
    userPeers.remove(peer);
}
```

### 4. Excessive `cleanUp`

I understand you don't want to wait for Guava to decide when the removals should actually happen, but forcing it on every access might be overkill (and create more contention), and you still depend on a call to `PeersContainer` to trigger the clean-up.

You could use some form of scheduler to call a global `PeersContainer.cleanUp()` method every minute, instead.

---

Updated to answer the comment.

### Unencapsulated modifications

By returning the actual `BlockingDeque<Peer>` from the `Cache` in `getPeers()`, you leave the possibility to modify the *shared* collection outside of the `PeersContainer` context, which may or not have an impact depending on the "friendliness" of the code using that data. If it's under your control and you never modify (even by accident) the collection, then it should be fine.

Otherwise, there are obviously 2 types of modifications:

- removing a `Peer`: OK, it's not there anymore, but to the `PeersContainer` it's not that big a deal, it can also happen if the entry expires in the cache
- adding a `Peer`: it won't have its `authorities` set, which means it might erase a `UserAuthorities` saved in the `authToRestore` cache by the removal of a previous `Peer` for the same session. Is it critical? I don't know, it's your application.

### Cache expiration

From the [`CacheBuilder` javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html):

> If expireAfterWrite or expireAfterAccess is requested entries may be evicted on each cache modification, on occasional cache accesses, or on calls to Cache.cleanUp(). Expired entries may be counted by Cache.size(), but will never be visible to read or write operations.

Even if your cache doesn't have enough write activity, with enough read activity the expired entries will eventually be removed. But even if they're not removed yet, the `Cache` will **never** return entries once they're expired (it wouldn't be doing a very good job otherwise).

The only reason why you may need to call `cleanUp()` in your case is because of the nature of your `RemovalListener`: you want to send some information back to the peer, so you want to do it in a timely manner after the entry has expired. It's up to you to define what "timely" means depending on your requirements, but in my opinion, it could be something between 15 seconds and 5 minutes.

Anyway, the way it's implemented now, if you have a single, inactive peer (so no calls at all to the methods of `PeersContainer`), it'll never receive a logout, whereas with a scheduled task it would happen no matter what. And on the other hand, if you have enough activity in the application, the clean-up will happen naturally with the writes or numerous reads, and an extra, scheduled `cleanUp` call won't cost much, whereas calling `cleanUp()` on each and every call will cause contention because the clean-up needs to sequentially lock all the segments in the `Cache` to clean them one by one.

---

Another round.

You don't really need a `ReadWriteLock`:

- the `readLock` in `getPeers()` is useless since the `Cache` itself is thread-safe
- the one in `restoreSession()` is also useless because it's already guarded by the `writeLock` in `addPeer()`, its caller.

So you could simplify a bit by using a simple `Lock`. The only parts you really need to guard by a lock are the ones where you modify the 2 `Caches`s.

Comment: thanks for broad response. 1) Outside the `PeerContainer` I should only iterate the collection, that's why a implemented `get` method. Of course I can return a copy of `BlocckingDeque`, but I can't imagine scenario when it's harmful. Can you help? 4) As I understand `Cache` proceeds cleanups only on write operations. Then to force cache to return actual data on read operations I should cleanup explicitly. Am I wrong?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I've gotten a new insight after reading your other SO questions and sleeping on it: answer updated again.

Comment: thanks I'll do that. But I still can't grasp how the second cache will be helpfull for me/

Comment: By "the 2 caches", I meant `peers` and `authToRestore`, not the extra cache in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22155141/1350869.